# Should I be using <field> instead of <input> tags for input?

Tags: html, forms, joomla

I'm asking this question after being puzzled by Joomla’s documentation here: https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

It looks as if they’re using `<field>` tags where I would typically use `<input>` tags. I searched w3.org and looked at the specs for HTML5, and can’t find any mention of a 'field' tag.

I understand that `<field>` is perfectly valid in an XML context, just not sure why they’re using it in place of `<input>` in what I would consider HTML forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no field tag in html because field tag is something special with joomla

from the documentation

> Form fields are fields in a HTML . Joomla! 2.5 and newer supply the JForm class to conveniently and flexibly create forms with a large amount of form fields. Each form field type is a subclass of JFormField.
>
> In addition to being a flexible page creation tool, JFormFields are used by Joomla! to allow administrators to configure Joomla! or its extensions without changing the underlying code. In Joomla! 1.5, this was handled by the now deprecated JParameter and JElement classes.
>
> To define form fields in the configuration of an extension, you must include them in a named fieldset, such as , that is within the  section of the  element in your XML manifest file.

to read more from here

https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this considered 'non-standard' from the HTML spec? I'm just wondering if  `<input>` instead of `<field>` would be more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Form fields are fields in a HTML . Joomla 2.5 and newer supply the JForm class to conveniently and flexibly create forms with a large amount of form fields. Each form field type is a subclass of JFormField.

You can read more about [Tag form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Tag_form_field_type)